# Grid Field Count Search in Channel Entries

Tags: channel-entries, search

Is there a way to filter `{exp:channel:entries}` based on the number of rows in a Grid field?

Answer (score 1):

Not natively, no. But you could use the Query module to populate the `entry_id` parameter:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="foo" entry_id="
    {exp:query sql="
        SELECT entry_id, count(*) AS count 
        FROM exp_channel_grid_field_XXX 
        GROUP BY entry_id 
        HAVING count > X" 
        backspace="1"}{entry_id}|"{/exp:query}
"}
```